# Trying to convert an ArrayList to String

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> idattributes=new ArrayList();
idattributes.add("7");
idattributes.add("10");
idattributes.add("12");
```

I'm trying to convert it to a string like this:

```
String listString = "";
for (String s : idattributes) {
      listString += s + "\t";
} 
System.out.println(listString);

I get: "7   10  12  "
```

How could I remove those multiple spaces? I just want a string "7 10 12"
Any other good way to convert idattributes to a String?
Thanks

Comment: Those aren't "multiple spaces;" they're tabs, which is exactly what `"\t"` tells the code to do. Why not use `List#toString()`?

Comment: "\t" is a tab. if you want just a simple space, say so: listString += s + " ";

Comment: If you want a single space between items, then use `" "` instead of `"\t"`. If you mean the spaces at the end, `trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it pays not to try to be too smart and use an inefficient trim() :)

```
String listString = "";
for (String s : idattributes) {
    listString += s + " ";
} 
listString = listString.trim();
```

Unless you meant to have the tab in there, in which case

```
listString += s + "\t"
```

is fine, but the trim() is still required.

Answer (score 0):

to get `"7 10 12"` code has to be like

```
String listString = "";
for (String s : idattributes) {
  listString += s + " ";
} 
System.out.println(listString.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

```
String listString = "";
for (String s : idattributes) {
      listString += s + " ";
} 
listString = listString.trim();

System.out.println(listString);
```

Or,

```
System.out.println(idattributes.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, replace the "\t" by " ", then choose between :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < idattributes.size() ; i++)
{
    listString += itattributes.get(i);
    if (i != idattributes.size() - 1)
        listString += " ";
}
```

and :

your code, followed by `listString.trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Another good way is to use Guava's Joiner class.

```
 String listString = Joiner.on(" ").join( idattributes );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to use StringBuilder instead of String. You can find more info [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : idattributes) {
      sb.append(s).append(" ");
} 
String listString = sb.toString().trim()l
System.out.println(listString);
```

Also you can use the [**Joiner**](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) of the Guava lib.

```
String listString = Joiner.on(" ").join( idattributes ).trim();
```